# How to synchronise the scrolling between two different recycler views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app I am showing two `RecyclerView` in horizontal way. Left `RecyclerView` show pages present in each document and right `RecyclerView` show name of the document. For example consider there are two pdf document and name of the both the document is PDF_1 and PDF_2. Suppose consider PDF_1 document conatin 4 pages and PDF_2 document contain 2 pages.

Now in my right `RecyclerView` I am showing name of the document i.e PDF_1 and PDF_2. Same way in my left `RecyclerView` I am showing all the pages present in PDF_1 and PDF_2.

Now my requirement is, whenever I scroll item in left `RecyclerView`, based on which document page is visible in `RecyclerView`, I need to highlight the document name in right `RecyclerView`. E.g PDF_1 contain 4 page. So when we scroll the item in left `RecyclerView`, as soon as PDF_2 page is visible, we need to highlight PDF_2 name in right `RecyclerView`. Please refer below diagram for better understanding of what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: If you using `ViewHolder` pattern, you can try to do that in `onBindViewHolder()` method (when you fill item with data)

Comment: make use of onViewAttachedToWindow (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)), this method is called when a view is about to be visible

Comment: Can you guys explain me with some example. It will be great